# Can't debug my asp.net web app developped on visual studio 2015 and hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, visual-studio-2015

I am a telecom engineer, I have studied a little bit of coding but I am not a professional, I have to develop a c# asp.net app for my company and I have some issues with debugging my app with Visual Studio 2015. I hosted my app on IIS (not IIS Express, even if I don't understand the difference), when I hit debug (with Firefox, Google Chrome...) a message of error displays where it is written:

> unable to start debugging on the web server the remote server returned an error 400

I have litterally tried everything, can you please help me and give me solutions that I will understand (I am no professional), if you need a screen shot or something please let me know.

Comment: Can you not run and debug locally, that is, on your own pc?

Comment: can you run application without attaching debugger - I mean type url directly on browser address bar. Hopefully you will get some error. please provide that error

Comment: If you are debugging website hosted in IIS then you need to run visual studio in Administrator mode. (Right click snd run as administrator)

Comment: first you must run Visual Studio in Administrator mode, then press ctrl+alt+p and attach to process w3wp.exe ,before that you must open local website in your browser.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you all for your answers, @OleEHDufour yes it's my own PC, when I type http://localhost/webtest (which is the url of my app) I have the result I have designed on visual studio without any problem, 
 I am running in administrator mode and it's still not working, I wan attach the process and it debuggs but why can't it debugg and open the url on my browser just as I see on tutos

Comment: @RahulAgarwal  when I type localhost/webtest (which is the url of my app) I have the result I have designed on visual studio without any problem

Comment: @barzin.A  I am running in administrator mode and it's still not working, I can attach the process and it debuggs but why can't it debugg and open the url on my browser just as I see on tutos

Comment: @SurjitSD  I am running in administrator mode and it's still not working, I can attach the process and it debuggs but why can't it debugg and open the url on my browser just as I see on tutos

Comment: Can you explain why you want to debug the remote website? I hardly ever do that.

Comment: I don't know I just see people on tutos doing that, but since I have the result I want appearing on my browser I guess it's ok, right ?

Comment: Sure! You create a website in VS, debug locally and if everything's ok, you publish in production.

Comment: Thank you a lot @OleEHDufour

Answer (score 0):

Clarifications/details (based on comments, etc.), and since "just use localhost/foo" sounds too magical:

- if you're debugging on a *remote* web server (not your own PC), you'll have to setup the [*remote machine* to *allow* such](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer). This may or may not be feasible (not your server, etc. etc.).
- Hence Visual Studio provides [*local debugging* (`Express` or local `IIS`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications)
- What is [`IIS Express`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)?

---

> When I want to start a project I can eather store it on IIS or IIS Express

Sure, but you'll have to know how to set things up (see links)

> When I use IIS, and click on debug, I have error 400 and the browser doesnt open But When I use IIS Express and click on debug, it debugs, the browser opens and I have a 500.52 error

Set `debug=true`. It should give you error/exception detail(s) (also in link above)

> So I am storing my project on IIS (inetpub\wwwroot...) and when I design and write my code I just press start without debug and the browser opens with my app appearing

Same as above, that just means IIS is *running* your app just like any other ASP.Net app. It does not automatically mean you can *attach to it and debug*.

While you *can* certainly develop that way (using /wwwroot), you'll be better off deving in your own directory, using VS/IIS Express, and `publish` to IIS (as simple as file system copy). You'll also learn what `publish` means (compiling), what in all your code is "published"/needed in live/production. If you kept deving in IIS the way you are, you'll likely not know the difference.

IIS admin is a bigger topic (multiple apps, multiple sites, and associated configuration).

Comment: I am using my own PC

Comment: When I want to start a project I can eather store it on IIS or IIS Express

Comment: When I use IIS, and click on debug, I have error 400 and the browser doesnt open
But When I use IIS Express and click on debug, it debugs, the browser opens and I have a 500.52 error

Comment: So I am storing my project on IIS (inetpub\wwwroot...) and when I design and write my code I just press start without debug and the browser opens with my app appearing

Comment: what do you think

Comment: @AbdouElMalyaniIdrissi updated answer with your comments with advice.

Comment: Okey, thanks a lot for your answers, I'll try all what you have suggested